# Regular expression to extract specific part of a URL

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of URLs and need to extract a certain part of it. I've tried using a regex tester to see if my attempts worked, but they were no good.

The URLs I have are in this format: https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/1976.shtml

I ned to extract the three letters after "teams/" (so for the example above, I need "MIL")

Does anyone have any idea how to get the correct regular expression to get this working? Thanks.

Comment: Note that if the URLs are literally all in that same format, same domain, same path, then you can avoid regular expressions and use a simple substring: `stringr::str_sub(url, 42, 44)` - I've provided an answer below with both regex and substring solutions using `stringr`.

Answer (score 1):

**1) basename/dirname** Try this:

```
u <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/1976.shtml" # input data

basename(dirname(u))
## [1] "MIL"
```

**2) sub** or with a regular expression:

```
sub(".*teams/(.*?)/.*", "\\1", u)
## [1] "MIL"
```

**3) strsplit**  Split the string on / and take the second last component.

```
s <- strsplit(u, "/")[[1]]
s[length(s) - 1]
## [1] "MIL"
```

**4) gsub** Since the required substring is all upper case and no other characters in the input are this `gsub` which removes all characters that are not upper case letters would work:

```
gsub("[^A-Z]", "", u)
## [1] "MIL"
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know this was at all possible. Regular expressions always give me a headache. Thank you for this brilliant trick.

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to achieve this using regexp's. Here's one:

```
url <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/1976.shtml"

gsub(".+teams/(\\w{3}).+$", "\\1", url);
#[1] "MIL"
```

Comment: Thanks, Maurits. I'll study this and hope this will help me when I need regular expressions in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
x <- c('https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/1976.shtml')
pattern <- "/teams/([^/]+)"
m <- regexec(pattern, x)
res = regmatches(x, m)[[1]]
res[2]
```

which yields

```
[1] "MIL"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `stringr` package to simplify your code when handling strings.

Use a regular expression with [positive lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to catch alphanumeric codes following the string "teams\":

```
stringr::str_extract(url, "(?<=teams\\/)[A-Z]*")
```

In your case, if the URLs literally all begin with the same string `https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/` then you can avoid regex entirely and use a simple substring to get the three-letter code which follows:

```
stringr::str_sub(url, 42, 44)
```

Here are the results:

```
> url <- "https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/MIL/1976.shtml"
> 
> stringr::str_extract(url, "(?<=teams\\/)[A-Z]*")
[1] "MIL"
> 
> stringr::str_sub(url, 42, 44)
[1] "MIL"
```